# How can I perform some actions after that several promises have been resolved in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Suppose that I have two method which returns promises.

```
function method1() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   // some actions
   deferred.resolve();

   return deferred.promise;
}

function method2() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   // some actions
   deferred.resolve();

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

I want to fait for finishing both methods and then perform some actions.
Some sort of

```
(method1(), method2()).then(function() {
   //some actions
});
```

It doesn't matter in what order the methods (method1 and method2) will be performed.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) which does exactly this:

```
$q.all([method1(), method2()]).then(function() {
   //some actions
});
```